# Splitting a string based on locating a varying code (with a similar format)

Tags: r, regex, string, parsing, character

I uploaded a `txt` file in to `R` as follows: `Election_Parties <- readr::read_lines("Election_Parties.txt")`
Let's say the following text was in the file:

```
P23-Andalusian Social Democratic Party (Partido Social-Demócrata Andaluz [PSDA])
P24-Andalusian Socialist Movement (Movimiento Socialista Andaluz [MSA])
P235-Andalusian Socialist Party-Andalucian Party (Partido Socialista Andalucista-Partido
Andalucista [PSA-PA])
P26-Andalusist Party (Partido Andalucista [PA])
P217-Andecha Astur (Andecha Astur [AA])
```

I would like to have all information about a party on one line, no matter how long it is. So:

```
P25-Andalusian Socialist Party-Andalucian Party (Partido Socialista Andalucista-Partido
Andalucista [PSA-PA])
```

Should become:

```
P25-Andalusian Socialist Party-Andalucian Party (Partido Socialista Andalucista-Partido Andalucista [PSA-PA])
```

I guess I should first put all the text together:

```
Election_Parties <- paste(Election_Parties, collapse=" ")
```

And then split it when it finds the combination `P**-` or `P***-`. How do I write this last part?

EDIT:

The actual data I would like to apply this to looks more like this:

```
BOLIVIA
P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento 
Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR])
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas 
de Colombia)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
BOLIVIA
P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario 
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas de Colombia)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
strsplit(paste(Election_Parties, collapse=" "), "\\s+(?=P\\d+-)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/ZYJM27930).

Output:

```
[1] "P23-Andalusian Social Democratic Party (Partido Social-Demócrata Andaluz [PSDA])"                              
[2] "P24-Andalusian Socialist Movement (Movimiento Socialista Andaluz [MSA])"                                       
[3] "P235-Andalusian Socialist Party-Andalucian Party (Partido Socialista Andalucista-Partido Andalucista [PSA-PA])"
[4] "P26-Andalusist Party (Partido Andalucista [PA])"                                                               
[5] "P217-Andecha Astur (Andecha Astur [AA])"
```

The `\s+(?=P\d+-)` pattern matches 1+ whitespaces that are followed with `P`, 1+ digits, `-`, but the `P<numbers>-` is not consumed since the pattern resides in the positive lookahead construct that is a zero-width assertion. Due to this lookahead, the `perl=TRUE` argument is necessary to process the regex with the PCRE regex engine.

Comment: Is there anyway to add an exception to this solution? Resulting in it skipping the line if the line starts with `P00-`? I am trying to combine your answer with the question I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993738/converting-text-to-a-data-frame-based-on-headers

Comment: @Tom It is very easy: `"\\s+(?=P(?!00-)\\d+-)"`

Comment: Thank you very much, that almost works perfectly. The only problem it creates is that it puts to consecutive `P00-` lines together in string. Is it possible to skip empty lines of codes and codes with nothing else than capital letters (no symbols, numbers etc). ?

Comment: @Tom Could you please clarify? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8hUIFs/1/). Please update with the new data to showcase the issue

Comment: I have updated the data: https://regex101.com/r/8hUIFs/2 Ideally both the `P00-` would be a separate line (this has to do with applying the solution of the link I provided in the comments). If both `P00-` are separate lines, I can replace them with `" "`(nothing) to get to the example from the link. Sorry I understand it is a little bit unclear. I messed it up by thinking I could tackle the issue in two steps.

Comment: Please also see the EDIT. Your solution for the `EDIT data` creates two lines each `P***` instead of one.

Comment: @Tom Please check https://rextester.com/QDCHY91357. I do not quite get the problem with `P00`. Do you mean you need to remove all consecutive `P00-` substrings with one occurrence? See https://rextester.com/QIIWO6997

Comment: So this solution is really, really, really close to what I want. The only thing I need is for the empty line (between the parties Bolivia and Columbia) to remain (See `DESIRED OUTPUT`). Thank you for helping me out so much by the way..

Comment: You did exactly what I want now, but somehow it doesn't work on the `.txt` file I have. I guess there is more going on in the text than in the example I gave. Perhaps I should simply make a new question, which more example data? Is there a possibility to upload a `.txt` file?

Comment: @Tom Use pastebin.com

Comment: I made a new question with the text file via pastebin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006401/correcting-strings-scattered-over-multiple-lines-based-on-locating-a-varying-cod