# Correcting strings scattered over multiple lines based on locating a varying code (with headers)

Tags: r, regex, string, parsing, character

I uploaded a `.txt` file in to `R` as follows: `Election_Parties <- readr::read_lines("Election_Parties.txt")` The following text is in the file: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/KKu9FmF6).

The text more or less looks as follows (Please use actual file for solution!):

```
BOLIVIA
P1-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento 
Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR])
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas 
de Colombia)
```

I would like to have all information about a party on one line, no matter how long it is.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
BOLIVIA
P1-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario 
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas de Colombia)
```

The following answer: `strsplit(paste(Election_Parties, collapse=" "), "\\s+(?=P\\d+-)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]` from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993208/splitting-a-string-based-on-locating-a-varying-code-with-a-similar-format), works to correct the strings, but it does not deal with the headers (BOLIVIA, COLUMBIA & the empty lines) properly. Dealing with this is important because I want to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993738/converting-text-to-a-data-frame-based-on-headers/58994218?noredirect=1#comment104240768_58994218) solution afterwards.

Although I got an answer in the commentsof that post which worked on the example, it does not work on my text file.

How can I adapt the solution to deal with (leave alone) the headers and empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned the whole thing into a tidy and useful format. Have a look:

First I read in the file:

```
lines <- readr::read_lines("https://pastebin.com/raw/jSrvTa7G")
head(lines)
#> [1] ""                                                                                                        
#> [2] "ALBANIA"                                                                                                 
#> [3] "P1-Democratic Alliance Party (Partia Aleanca Democratike [AD])"                                          
#> [4] "P2-National Unity Party (Partia Uniteti Kombëtar [PUK])"                                                 
#> [5] "P3-Social Spectrum Parties-Party of National Unity (Partitë e Spektrit Social-Partia e Unitetit Kombëtar"
#> [6] "[PSHS-PUK])"
```

I split the raw format into entries by looking for empty lines, which occur just before a new entry:

```
entries <- split(lines, cumsum(grepl("^$|^ $", lines)))
```

Then I loop through every entry and turn it into a `tibble`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- lapply(entries, function(entry) {
  entry <- entry[!grepl("^$|^ $", entry)] # remove empty elements
  header <- entry[1] # first non empty is the header
  entry <- tail(entry, -1)  # remove header from entry
  desc <- str_extract(entry, "^P\\d+-")  # extract description

  for (l in which(is.na(desc))) { # collapse lines that go over 2 elements
    entry[l - 1] <- paste(entry[l - 1], entry[l], sep = " ")
  }

  entry <- entry[!is.na(desc)]
  desc <- desc[!is.na(desc)]

  # turn into nice format
  df <- tibble::tibble(
    header,
    desc,
    entry
  )
  df$entry <- str_replace_all(df$entry, fixed(df$desc), "") # remove description from entry
  return(df)
}) %>% 
  bind_rows() # turn list into one data.frame
```

And now we have a really nice `data.frame` we can easily work with:

```
df
#> # A tibble: 5,525 x 3
#>    header  desc  entry                                                     
#>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>                                                     
#>  1 ALBANIA P1-   Democratic Alliance Party (Partia Aleanca Democratike [AD~
#>  2 ALBANIA P2-   National Unity Party (Partia Uniteti Kombëtar [PUK])      
#>  3 ALBANIA P3-   Social Spectrum Parties-Party of National Unity (Partitë ~
#>  4 ALBANIA P4-   Alliance Party for Solidarity and Welfare (Partia Aleanca~
#>  5 ALBANIA P5-   Albanian Democratic Union-Alliance for Freedom, Justice a~
#>  6 ALBANIA P6-   Liberal Democrat Party (Partia Bashkimi Liberal Demokrat ~
#>  7 ALBANIA P7-   Linking Blerta Albanian Party (Partia Lidhja e Blertë Shq~
#>  8 ALBANIA P8-   Democratic Movement for Integration (Lëvizja Demokratike ~
#>  9 ALBANIA P9-   Movement of Human Rights and Freedoms Party (Partia Lëviz~
#> 10 ALBANIA P10-  Socialist Party of Albania (Partia Socialiste e Shqipëris~
#> # ... with 5,515 more rows
```

The strings which are scattered over multiple lines are corrected in this bit:

```
  for (l in which(is.na(desc))) { # collapse lines that go over 2 elements
    entry[l - 1] <- paste(entry[l - 1], entry[l], sep = " ")
  }
```

`desc` will be `NA` in cases where the line does not begin with e.g., "P1-" (1 can be any number). If this is the case the line is collapse with the previous entry. Later on `NA` are removed leaving the information only in the correct line.

Comment: Hey JBGruber, I recently noticed that your code somehow deletes information and I regretfully do not understand your code well enough to see where it might happen. I made a new question for clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355505/finding-the-cause-of-an-unwanted-deletion-within-an-lappy-function Would be great if you could take a look.