# Finding the cause of an unwanted deletion within an lappy function

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, stringr, readr

I uploaded a .txt file in to R as follows: `Election_Parties <- readr::read_lines("Election_Parties.txt")` The following text is in the file: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/FTV3Gded).

The text more or less looks as follows (Please use actual file for solution!):

```
BOLIVIA
P1-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento 
Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR])
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas 
de Colombia)
```

I would like to have all information about a party on one line, no matter how long it is.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
BOLIVIA
P1-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario 
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])
P20-Tupak Katari Revolutionary Movement (Movimiento Revolucionario Tupak Katari [MRTK])

COLOMBIA
P1-Democratic Aliance M-19 (Alianza Democratica M-19 [AD-M19])
P2-National Popular Alliance (Alianza Nacional Popular [ANAPO])
P3-Indigenous Authorities of Colombia (Autoridades Indígenas de Colombia)
```

I have a solution that almost completely does the trick by @JBGruber, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006401/correcting-strings-scattered-over-multiple-lines-based-on-locating-a-varying-cod):

```
lines <- readr::read_lines("https://pastebin.com/raw/jSrvTa7G")
head(lines)
entries <- split(lines, cumsum(grepl("^$|^ $", lines)))

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- lapply(entries, function(entry) {
  entry <- entry[!grepl("^$|^ $", entry)] # remove empty elements
  header <- entry[1] # first non empty is the header
  entry <- tail(entry, -1)  # remove header from entry
  desc <- str_extract(entry, "^P\\d+-")  # extract description

  for (l in which(is.na(desc))) { # collapse lines that go over 2 elements
    entry[l - 1] <- paste(entry[l - 1], entry[l], sep = " ")
  }

  entry <- entry[!is.na(desc)]
  desc <- desc[!is.na(desc)]

  # turn into nice format
  df <- tibble::tibble(
    header,
    desc,
    entry
  )
  df$entry <- str_replace_all(df$entry, fixed(df$desc), "") # remove description from entry
  return(df)
}) %>% 
  bind_rows() # turn list into one data.frame
```

But it somehow deletes information. For example, this information:

```
P1-Movement for a Prosperous Czechoslovakia (Hnutie za prosperujúce Česko + Slovensko
[HZPČS])
P2-Social Democracy (Sociálna demokracia [SD])
P3-Association for Workers in Slovakia (Združenie robotníkov Slovenska [ZRS])
```

I don't understand the code well enough to see where this deletion might occur, or how to check step by step where it occurs (as everything happens within `lapply`). Can anyone help?

Please note that solutions using `data.table` are just as welcome.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it deletes information? The three you list above are all in the `data.frame`. Test with `grep("Movement for a Prosperous Czechoslovakia", df$entry, value = TRUE)` etc. or in RStudio Viewer.

Comment: The file you linked does not seem to be the same as in the original question. The answer was based on the fact that entries where separated by an empty line. In this file there aren't any empty lines. The parsing would be a bit different for that reason.

Comment: @JBGruber My apologies, I have adapted the file now. I have manually checked because something did not add up. Then I noticed that the first 49 parties for Slovenia were not there. I'll add your suggestion.

Comment: Ah ok. I adapted the answer to work with the new structure. Also check the last paragraph of the answer. And let me know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the answer doesn't work properly anymore is that the file has changed slightly. The original answer was based on the fact that entries were separated by an empty line. These lines are gone. But entries are now separated by a line that only contains "P00-". We can use this as the separator instead.

```r
lines <- readr::read_lines("https://pastebin.com/raw/KKu9FmF6")

entries <- split(lines, cumsum(grepl("P00-$", lines)))

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df <- lapply(entries, function(entry) {
  entry <- entry[!grepl("P00-$", entry)] # remove empty elements
  header <- entry[1] # first non empty is the header
  entry <- tail(entry, -1)  # remove header from entry
  desc <- str_extract(entry, "^P\\d+-")  # extract description

  for (l in which(is.na(desc))) { # collapse lines that go over 2 elements
    entry[l - 1] <- paste(entry[l - 1], entry[l], sep = " ")
  }

  entry <- entry[!is.na(desc)]
  desc <- desc[!is.na(desc)]

  # turn into nice format
  df <- tibble::tibble(
    header,
    desc,
    entry
  )
  df$entry <- str_replace_all(df$entry, fixed(df$desc), "") # remove description from entry
  return(df)
}) %>% 
  bind_rows() # turn list into one data.frame
```

I checked if the information you listed above is still missing and this is  not the case:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(entry, "Movement for a Prosperous Czechoslovakia|Sociálna demokraci|Association for Workers in Slovakia"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   header      desc  entry                                                       
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr>                                                       
#> 1 P00-SLOVAK… P1-   Movement for a Prosperous Czechoslovakia (Hnutie za prosper…
#> 2 P00-SLOVAK… P2-   Social Democracy (Sociálna demokracia [SD])                 
#> 3 P00-SLOVAK… P3-   Association for Workers in Slovakia (Združenie robotníkov S…
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I tried to make the answer as clear as possible, but I understand that it is often hard to wrap your head around other people's code. One thing that always helps me is to run the solution line by line and check how the objects change. Since most of the important stuff is hidden in the loop, you can simulate one run of `lapply` by creating an example entry like this: `entry <- entries[[1]]`. Now you can the lines inside `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could I ask for a favour? For some weird reason, after first working correctly, the problem comes back (see EDIT). Would it be posssible to put a pastebin link of the solution in?

Answer (score 1):

A pure base R alternative of @JBGruber's answer:

```
txt <- readLines("https://pastebin.com/raw/KKu9FmF6")

txtgrps <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("P00-$", txt)))

l <- lapply(txtgrps, function(grp) {
  grp <- tail(grp, -1)
  country <- gsub("^P\\d+-", "", grp[1])
  grp <- tail(grp, -1)
  grp <- tapply(grp, cumsum(grepl("^P\\d+-", grp)), paste, collapse = " ")
  code <- sub("(P\\d+)-.*", "\\1", grp)
  party <- gsub("^P\\d+-", "", grp)
  df <- data.frame(country, code, party)
  return(df)
})

df <- do.call(rbind, l)
```

which gives:

```
> head(df)
    country code                                                                                                                                                   party
1.1 ALBANIA   P1                                                                                             Democratic Alliance Party (Partia Aleanca Democratike [AD])
1.2 ALBANIA   P2                                                                                                    National Unity Party (Partia Uniteti Kombëtar [PUK])
1.3 ALBANIA   P3                                       Social Spectrum Parties-Party of National Unity (Partitë e Spektrit Social-Partia e Unitetit Kombëtar [PSHS-PUK])
1.4 ALBANIA   P4                                                          Alliance Party for Solidarity and Welfare (Partia Aleanca për Mirëqenie dhe Solidaritet [AMS])
1.5 ALBANIA   P5 Albanian Democratic Union-Alliance for Freedom, Justice and Welfare (Partia Bashkimi Demokrat Shqiptar-Aleanca për Liri, Drejtësi dhe Mirëqenie [BDSH])
1.6 ALBANIA   P6                                                                                         Liberal Democrat Party (Partia Bashkimi Liberal Demokrat [BLD])
```

---

For the new input, you could adapt the solution to:

```
txt <- readLines("https://pastebin.com/raw/FTV3Gded")

txtgrps <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("^$|^ $", txt)))
# based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006739/2204410

l <- lapply(txtgrps, function(grp) {
  grp <- tail(grp, -1)
  country <- grp[1]
  grp <- tail(grp, -1)
  grp <- tapply(grp, cumsum(grepl("^P\\d+", grp)), paste, collapse = " ")
  code <- sub("(P\\d+).*", "\\1", grp)
  party <- substring(sub("^P\\d+", "", grp), 2)
  df <- data.frame(country, code, party)
  return(df)
})

df <- do.call(rbind, l)
```

Comment: Hey Jaap, could I ask for a favour? For some weird reason, after first working correctly, the problem comes back (see EDIT).  Would it be posssible to put a pastebin link of the solution in?

Comment: Thanks Jaap, but your code worked fine in first instance (I have both files available, so i can use either). I think it is more likely I have some sort of encoding problem going on (if I apply your last approach, almost all parties are from Bermuda). I think there is nothing wrong with any code or with the file but perhaps with my computer, that is why I was asking for a pastebin.

Comment: @Tom Upon checking the output df, I see I have the same problem :-/

Comment: I just tested, I still have the same problem as the picture I posted under EDIT :(

Comment: @Tom There is an encoding problem in the text data: the `-` is for some rows encoded differently. I've adapted the solution. It should work now.

Comment: It works! Thank you from the bottom of my heart. I thought I was going crazy..

Comment: @Tom For the future: if you suspect you have an encoding problem, the `charToRaw`-function could help. Using `slov <- tail(txtgrps[[46]], -2); s <- sapply(substr(slov, 1, 4), charToRaw); s[which(names(s) == "P33-") + (-3:0)]` I could see that the `-` was encoded differently before `P33-` (which is the first correct one for Slovenia in your screenshot).